# Passenger Standalone won't restart on touching restart.txt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I built a little deploy script that works similar to Capistrano in that way, that it checks out a Rails application to a timestamped directory and sets the `current` link to that when all went well.
The problem is, that on touching the tmp/restart.txt, nothing happens and I wonder if it has something to do with Passenger Standalone being started from within the timestamped directory after `cd /path/to/app/current`. So if i update the current link, passenger doesn't see the things happening in that link's new target directory but stays in the old one, thinking life is beautiful.

Are these assumptions correct and if so, what can I do? If not, what can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the current as first parameter

Comment: here is whole tutorial http://niczsoft.com/2011/03/passenger-standalone-with-god-on-rvm/